# Best array type for a data member of an object for C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I've recently started learning C++ (having already a lot of experience with C).

I've briefly looked at `vector<..>` and `array<..>`.

I was wondering what is the best array type for a data member of an object for C++. Please keep in mind I want encapsulation, so this data member will be private - so I will need getter and setter functions for it.

I know the length of the array (the length will be kept constant, so no reallocation will be needed).

Would the traditional `int array[100];` be the best?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: `std::array` has more intuitive syntax if you want to copy, pass/return by reference than C-array.

Comment: Try `std::array<your_class, 100>`.

Comment: Will the size be known and fixed at time of compilation? Will the size change during run-time?

Comment: You may want to check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-ieS3SGFzo)

Comment: Thanks.

I have another question.

If I use array<int, 100> as the type, in the getter function, do I have to explicitly write "array<int, 100>" in the return type of the function signature or is there a way I can just write "array<int>" - which looks neater but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You have to use `array<int, 100>`, so the client code knows exactly how many elements to create space for / copy / destroy etc..

Comment: You can use auto returntype, if you have a c++14 compiler

Comment: BUT: if you just return a reference to the array, you don't do any encapsulation at all.

Comment: A `vector` supports *moving* the entire vector, without moving the individual elements. The array types do not.

Answer (score 2):

When you know at compile time the length of the array you should probably go with `array`. You **could** go for `vector` too, but that might make somebody think that the size could potentially change (or are at least not determined at compile time). If you're using large arrays and the variable lives in local scope you should consider using `vector` anyway.

Using `int array[100];` could also be an alternative, it has some advantages and some disadvantage.

The advantage is that it might be slightly faster to set up (it would probably be faster than `vector` anyway) and you can initialize it in the classical way. Another is that some implementation will allow for classic array with variable length decided on instantiation (I don't think it has made it into the standard, but it's rather easy to support), if of course you accept to rely on the implementation supporting this extension.

The disadvantage is that you don't get easy full access to the STL methods (you still have the possibility via `std::begin` and `std::end` to get an iterator for the array), but also that if created as local variable you're bound to use stack space for storing the objects as opposed to `vector` which would need to dynamically allocate space for the storage (`array` can potentially use stack space).

Comment: For a C-style array you can use `std::begin()`, `std::end()` to get access to the stl methods.

Comment: @graham.reeds Yes, but that would only give you access to the part that is iteration over the array. You could maybe also use the other (assignment, comparision, `swap` etc), but not as convinient as if you used an `array` directly.

Comment: Not as convenient as using `array` or `vector` but when you have a C-style arrays they are a godsend. I use them extensively on a large legacy code base to leverage the STL algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know C, I'll give you an analogy in terms of that language.

`std::vector` is used like `int* array = malloc(sizeof int * size)` is used in C. If the array is big and you don't want the owning object to be big, then use `std::vector`. This is important if you want your object to be efficiently movable or swappable. If you consider `std::vector`, don't forget to evaluate `std::deque` as well.

A manually allocated dynamic array has no advantages over `std::vector`.

`std::array` is used like `int array[100]` array is used in C. The lack of separate dynamic allocation makes creation of `std::array` fast. If you have many objects that contain small arrays, then `std::array` might be a good choice. If the size of the array is not constant or not known at compile time, then you cannot use `std::array`. In that case, use `std::vector` instead.

A regular C-style array does have one small advantage over `std::array`. Which is that when you initialize it with curly brackets, you may omit the size. With `std::array`, you must specify the size even if it seems redundant. This slightly nicer syntax does not outweigh the advantages of `std::array`, though. One significant advantage of `std::array` is that unlike a regular C-style array, it can be passed as a parameter and returned by value.

So, in conclusion, the bestness of an array depends on your needs. In some case, `std::array` is better and in others `std::vector` is. In some cases, `std::array` is not an option at all. There's no need for the C-style alternatives.